# Laravel Read User id in Controller constructor

Tags: authentication, laravel

In my controller(s), instead of fetching`Auth::id()` in each method, I've set up an `$id` property in the controller's class and fetched it once in the constructor. then, in the rest of the methods i'm just refering `$this->id`, is it considered safe or am I doing something wrong?

Code Sample: http://pastebin.com/pvju54eh

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is inject the `Guard` instance in your controller and then assign the currently logged in user (if there is one) to a class property:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->user = $this->auth->user();
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // Get logged in user’s ID
        $userId = $this->user->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Broshi It will, but it’s better to use declare dependencies via interfaces than façades.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any major problems with this approach even though I have not seen approach used often.

Myself I find it easier to get the $request->user() in controller from Request though.